# scipy.optimize.minimize How to manage different units?

Tags: optimization, gradient-descent, scipy

I am wondering how [spicy.optimize.minimize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) manages different units in the searched vector. My vector is `[x,y,z,yaw,pitch,roll]`. The first three are translations in `mm` whereas the latter three are rotations in `radians`, which means sampling into the first three dimensions is different compared to the rotation ones? I figured I had to use `degrees` to get better results for my problem than `radians` in fact.

--- EDIT ---
Per request, more on the optimization:

I have lidar readings (1 dimensional vector of distances that is in-plane in 3D) in a perfectly known environment and I want to determine the lidar position & inclination `(x, y, z, yaw, pitch, roll)` - 6DOF.
I have a *CAD* (point cloud) model of the environment.

My approach to determine the solution is to convert the lidar readings into Carthesian coordinates `pl <= (x, y, z)` based on a default origin.
Then, I try to optimize by sampling my 6 DOF solution space, apply that whole transformation to my lidar readings and determine the distance of each lidar Cartesian point `pl` to it's nearest CAD model neighbor.

I minimize over the mean distance `np.mean(abs(pls - CAD))` as my score and feed that into `scipy.optimize.minimize` which performs the sampling and optimization for me.

My solutions are ok, but not near optimal. Hence I believe that sampling could be improved if it would account for the unit difference. The alternative would be to make this a two-step process, translations first, rotations then.

Comment: It doesn't "manage units" at all. It's up to you to decide how to parameterize the function.

Comment: How could I adjust the function for sampling at different rates at the same time?

Comment: @El Dude Can you further explain the question in your above comment? I think you will need to further describe your optimization problem to get a useful answer to that, as I suspect that no one knows what you're asking.

Comment: I added that if it makes it clearer

Comment: Perhaps your issue is not the "unit", but the formulation of the problem, which I don't understand. I don;t understand what your sampling is. Are you running minimize one iteration at a time, and evaluating something which gets converted into the objective function at that point? Your description of how you convert measurements into an objective function to be minimized is rather vague, and could encompass a variety of good and not so good formulations. I don;t think this forum is a good fit for your problem. I am deleting my answer as it seems irrelevant to your real difficulty.

Comment: Thanks @MarkL.Stone. Which forum would you recommend then?

Comment: Perhaps https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/ , but you'll have to proviide much more detail on your model formulation, or it may not be well received.